# Xcode 4.3 can't find Carbon libs on 10.7

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, macos-carbon

I am trying to compile a legacy Carbon app on Xcode 4.6, that used to compile nicely on 10.6, but doesn't on 10.8 and can't see to be able to find the Carbon or QT libs.

How can I connect them back?

Thanks,

Bill

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that I needed to copy the 10.6 SDK to the the XCode app:

I found an old version and dragged a copy of:

*/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk*

to:

*/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs*

It now sits along side the MacOSX10.7.sdk and MacOSX10.8.sdk

After restarting XCode, remember to go into build settings and set the Base SDK to OS X 10.6

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11705378/123777