# Moving Carbon project to later Xcode

Tags: xcode, macos, macos-carbon

I'm trying to dig up and work on an old carbon application. Using Xcode 4.3.3, I find that Carbon.r is missing in the project.  Even when I target Mac OS 10.6 rather than 10.7, as suggested by [Xcode 4.3 can't find Carbon libs on 10.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17615420/xcode-4-3-cant-find-carbon-libs-on-10-7)

I suspect support is there, I just can't see how to "engage" it.  or is 4.3.3 too late a version?

What is the latest version of Xcode that has support for Carbon?  I'll boot back to an old MacOS if necessary to make this work.

Ken

Comment: The other question you reference is about using the 10.6 SDK, not "target Mac OS 10.6".  Not the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

There are degrees of support for Carbon.  I'm using Xcode 4.6.3 under Lion for a partly-Carbon app, but I had to make a couple of adjustments:

1. I can't edit Carbon nibs with the version of Interface Builder built into Xcode, and the old separate version won't run under Lion.  I have Snow Leopard Server running under VMWare Fusion to edit my nibs.
2. I'm using the OS 10.6 SDK, which does not come with this version of Xcode.  So, I opened up the Xcode app package, and in the `Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs` subfolder, I added a symbolic link to the 10.6 SDK living in a copy of Xcode 3.2.6.

Comment: P.S. The Interface Builder from Xcode 3.2.6 is now working for me under Lion.  I don't know what was wrong or how it got fixed.